# How to pass date parameters to execute sql stored procedure in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**This way works:**

```
import pandas
import pyodbc
import datetime as dt  

server = 'myserver'
db = 'mydb' 
myparams = ['2017-02-01','2017-02-28', None]  # None substitutes NULL in sql

connection_string = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};server='+server+';DATABASE='+ db+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
df = pandas.read_sql_query('EXEC PythonTest_Align_RSrptAccountCurrentMunich @EffectiveDateFrom=?,@EffectiveDateTo=?,@ProducerLocationID=?', connection_string, params = myparams)
```

**But this way does not work:**

```
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()
prev_monday = today - dt.timedelta(days=9)
prev_sunday = today - dt.timedelta(days=3)

myparams = [prev_monday,prev_sunday, None]  # None substitutes NULL in sql

connection_string = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};server='+server+';DATABASE='+ db+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
df = pandas.read_sql_query('EXEC PythonTest_Align_RSrptAccountCurrentMunich @EffectiveDateFrom=?,@EffectiveDateTo=?,@ProducerLocationID=?', connection_string, params = myparams)
```

**Error message:**

```
    cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'EXEC PythonTest_Align_RSrptAccountCurrentMunich @EffectiveDateFrom=?,@EffectiveDateTo=?,@ProducerLocationID=?': ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Is there specific way for passing date parameters in python?

Comment: I've not executed a stored procedure in pandas before (although trying to figure out how to do this in databricks..), but can you try `pd.read_sql()` instead ?

Comment: Thanks. But I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess here is that SQL can't handle pandas datetime values,

try passing the datetime values into strigns using `strftime`

```
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()
prev_monday = (today - dt.timedelta(days=9)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
prev_sunday = (today - dt.timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

myparams = [prev_monday,prev_sunday, None]
print(myparams)
['2019-10-14', '2019-10-20', None]
```

Comment: What's funny is that '{}'.format(dt.date.today()) gives '2019-10-23' which is the same string notation. That's why it's a bit puzzling

Comment: With this approach it returns empty dataframe

Comment: but the stored procedure executes? have you tried it in SQL to see if the values exist in the dB?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I switched to development environment, there is no data there. Works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @oleg interesting wonder if sql alchemy has the same behavior, thank you.